# Pb Free devices

Tags: pcb-design, integrated-circuit

We usually find in datasheets of Integrated circuit in features section the following statement:

*Pb free devices,
*Halide free device,

What is the advantage for an IC to be **Pb or Halide free**?

Comment: In many cases, use of lead free leads (Pb = lead) and halogen or halide free plastic is required by rules or laws so that consumer products which contain lead or halogens cannot be sold. This is primarily a regulatory issue, rather than a functional issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lead (Pb) and Halides can be hazardous to the environment. Since electronic devices will eventually be discarded and could contaminate the environment, many countries have passed rules to prevent their use.

The European Union has some of the strictest regulations, so if a company wants to sell to this large market, they must certify that a product does not contain the substances.

Comment: If we take the case of lead, how do we certify the Lead-Acid batteries that weight around 5kg and prevents ICs of few milligrams ?

Comment: @learndesign:  (Car and truck) batteries must be returned to the seller or other collection point for recycling.  They are also easier to pick out if one lands in the trash. Small devices often land in the trash and end up in a landfill - even though they should also be recycled.

Comment: @learndesign I guess until fairly recently there hasn't been a good alternative to lead acid batteries.

Comment: @learndesign Lead batteries are exempt from RoHS.

Comment: Lead acid batteries are recycled to a very high degree. The original materials can be recovered and re-used economically to make new lead acid batteries. Lithium ion batteries cannot be recycled economically. They are shredded and destroyed at end of life. I think lead acid is the more green choice in those cases where it works well (such as automotive starter batteries). Obviously for electric cars lead is not an option because of low energy density compared to Lithium.